# How to change values in a column into binary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

New to python and I am stuck at this. My CSV file contain this:

```
Sr,Gender
1,Male
2,Male
3,Female
```

Now I want to convert the Gender values into binary so the the file will look something like:

```
Sr,Gender
1,1
2,1
3,0
```

So, I imported the CSV file as `data` and ran this code:

```
data["Gender_new"]=1
data["Gender_new"][data["Gender"]=="Male"]=0
data["Gender_new"]=1=data["Gender_new"].astype(float)
```

But I got the error `ValueError: could not convert string 'Male' to float:`

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

Thanks

Comment: `data[‘Gender’] = (data[‘Gender’] ==‘Male’).astpye(int)`

Comment: As I'm not able to put  an answer, the  below  code would  be a  solution for  your  question:  `from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df['Gender_new'] = le.fit_transform(df['Gender_new'])`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

file = open("your.csv", "r")

data = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ",")

gender = {'male': 1,'female': 0}

data.Gender = [gender[item] for item in data.Gender]
print(data)
```

Or

```
data.Gender[data.Gender == 'male'] = 1
data.Gender[data.Gender == 'female'] = 0
print(data)
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good happy Coding !!

Answer (score 3):

You can do the conversion as you load the file:

```
d = pandas.read_csv('yourfile.csv', converters={'Gender': lambda x: int(x == 'Male')})
```

The `converters` argument takes a dictionary whose keys are the column names (or indices), and the value is a function to call for each item. The function must return the converted value.

The other way to do it is to convert it once you have the dataframe, as @DJK pointed in their comment:

```
data['Gender'] = (data['Gender'] == 'Male').astype(int)
```